# Add MediaPlayer object (Song) in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to start short song in my first simple app. Everything is working will until I add the "ourSong" object then I am getting the error on the emulator "Unfortunately MyApp has stopped" as I said if i comment "ourSong.start()"+ "ourSong.release()" out, the app works

```js
package com.example.helloworld;

import java.util.Timer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {

 MediaPlayer ourSong;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.splash);

  ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound);
  ourSong.start();

  Thread timer = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
     Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(
       "com.example.helloworld.MAINACTIVITY");
     startActivity(openStartingPoint);
    }
   }
  };

  timer.start();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPause();
  ourSong.release();
  finish();
 }

}
```

[image]

I appreciate any help

Comment: If you're crashing, post the stack trace from the logcat.

Comment: So i added screenshot of it. I tried to save it but the file was empty :(

Comment: MediaPlayer.create is failing and returning null.  You need to check for this.  And figure out why its failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem  in my case was the Emulator. I changed to my mobile device (S4) and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "raw" folder is located in "res".

For more details have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.view.SurfaceHolder).

Try it on a real device!

Comment: Why do you use "Splash.this" instead of "this" or "getApplicationContext()"? Also try another mp3 file!

Comment: It is so in the tutorial  I'm watching. I have already tried another mp3 file but without success and with the same error

Comment: Did you also check your "real" path (workspace if youre using Eclipse) for your /res/ folder? What kind of device do you use? A virtual one? For more details check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Comment: Yes i checked it. The song is there in the directory. I'm try on Nexus S virtual mashine.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked on a real device (Samsung S3) for me! If it is possible try the code not on a virtual machine!

Comment: I created a new virtual Machine Nexus 5 I can hear the song but the app does not work just the song!